# Spring Boot: Load Configuration run-time from dynamoDB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, netflix-archaius

As shown in the below documentation there are several ways to externalize Configuration,

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

However, I am dealing with a special case where spring boot config needs to load from AWS dynamoDB i.e loading all configuration from dynamoDB instead of using the default application.properties / application.yml (or any other property source file). So, there would be no properties specified locally and would be fetched at run-time from dynamoDB.

How can one achieve this?

I can see that `ConfigFileApplicationListener` is the place where loading configuration happens. Is there any way to override this and use one's own custom logic for ingesting properties or is there any other better way?

If there is a way directly through Netflix Archaius (https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Dynamo-DB), it would be very helpful.